What type of AD/security group can I get members of when using Power Automate
I'm sure I  can get members of a group from a SharePoint group and Office 365 groups.
Can I also get members from AD group or mail-enabled security group. We don't have power automate premium connector licenses so  not intending to use power automate premium connectors.
Any resources or tips would be appreciated.
Thanks.

It is possible to get members of Azure AD security group using Standard connectors in Power Automate.
You have to use the Microsoft Entra ID connector for this (below group I tried is mail-enabled security group):

Documentation: Microsoft Entra ID - Get group members

If you want to get only user accounts from nested Azure AD group, you will have to use Microsoft Graph API with the help of Office 365 Groups - Send an HTTP request V2 action in flow.
Check: Microsoft Graph - List group transitive members.
